# user-register.tpl.php javascript errors

Tags: theming, users

I've got a custom register template working by adding this in my template:

```
// Customize User Login
function THEME_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path){
$hooks = array();
// Make user-register.tpl.php available
 $hooks['user_register_form'] = array (
 'render element' => 'form',
 'path' => drupal_get_path('theme','THEME') .'/templates/user',
 'template' => 'user-register',
 'preprocess functions' => array('THEME_preprocess_user_register_form'),
);
return $hooks;
}
function THEME_preprocess_user_register_form(&$vars) {
$args = func_get_args();
array_shift($args);
$form_state['build_info']['args'] = $args;
$vars['form'] = drupal_build_form('user_register_form', $form_state['build_info']['args']);
}
```

The page works, but returns a javascript error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'confirmTitle' of undefined (user.js line 19)

Also, no validation errors are displayed if I try and submit the form with errors.

The template itself looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
<div class="left">
    <?php print render($form['field_first_name']); ?>
    <?php print render($form['field_last_name']); ?>
    <?php print render($form['field_chinese_name']); ?>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <?php print render($form['account']['mail']); ?>
    <?php print render($form['field_position']); ?>
    <?php print render($form['field_company']); ?>
</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <?php print render($form['account']['pass']['pass1']); ?>
    <?php print render($form['account']['pass']['pass2']); ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="last">
    <?php print render($form['field_keep_me_updated_with_news_']); ?>
    <?php print render($form['field_i_have_read_and_agree_to_t']); ?>
</fieldset>

<?php
    print drupal_render($form['actions']); 
    print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
    print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
    print drupal_render_children($form);
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

line 9 of user.js: var translate = settings.password;

settings.password is undefined. Any ideas?

---

I removed these sections and it works:

```
$args = func_get_args();
array_shift($args);
$form_state['build_info']['args'] = $args;
$vars['form'] = drupal_build_form('user_register_form', $form_state['build_info']['args']);
```

Any idea what these parts were supposed to do anyway?

Comment: You need to see what user.js line 19 tries to grab, and then analyse why it isn't there any more after your function takes place.

Comment: That is the line `$('input.password-confirm', outerWrapper).parent().prepend('<div class="password-confirm">' + translate['confirmTitle'] + ' <span></span></div>').addClass('confirm-parent');` I comment this out, and gives another error for another element. It seems that the template needs to mimic the default template with with containing divs - but the docs don't seem to say that.

Comment: It seems that JS has problems with `translate['confirmTitle']` being undefined. But the built-in user module wasn't changed since 2013 (except for 2 documentation commits), so it must be some other module that interfered. `translate` comes from `settings`, first line of behavior: `var translate = settings.password;`. Apparently it is defined, JS would complain at line 9 if it weren't, but somehow it does not contain what it should.

Comment: I've found it boils down to line 9: var translate = settings.password; The settings object doesn't contain the password property, but a default registration page does. Any ideas?

Comment: The form should already be built by the time you render it (so there should be no need to build it in the preprocess). If all you want to do is theme that form with a custom template, you should be able to add a `#theme` key to the form in a form alter. (Sorry if I've missed your overall goal!)

Comment: I'm seeing the same error when I use HOOK_form_user_register_form_alter() to turn registration into a multi-page form. For what it's worth, I'm not using drupal_build_form() and I'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me - modifying line 9 of user.js to add a fallback assignment.

```
var translate = settings.password || [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this patch to handle it [#patch_link](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/drupal-clean_up_user_module-1751434-25.patch)